# Unresolved reference: Engine (WallpaperService)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to extend `android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService.Engine` class in Kotlin, but I get "*Unresolved reference*" error:

[image: Unresolved reference: Engine]

Even though it is clearly imported above.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue is that the `WallpaperService.Engine` is a class enclosed within `WallpaperService` class (it is obvious once you see it), and is not static, and thus must be tied to a instance of a `WallpaperService` class, in other words, it must be declared as an `inner` class of a `WallpaperService` class:

```kotlin
import android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService

class MyWallpaperService : WallpaperService() {

    ...

    inner class MyEngine : Engine() {

    }

}
```